# Changing Alignment of YUI Multi Page Calendar

Tags: calendar, yui

I want to change the aligment of YUI  Multi Page Calendar Control from its default alignment "Horizontal" to "Vertical" is there any parameters required to change the same.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the documented configuration attributes for `CalendarGroup`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.CalendarGroup.html#configattributes) it does not appear to be possible to stack the months vertically.